# WebStorm HTML file is not showing code folding tags

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I am facing problem in WebStorm editor. When I use any Angular or React project the HTML files are having code folding options. But when I use the simple HTML/CSS/JS project. HTML file is not showing code folding options.

This is really weird how to enable code folding for specific project types?

[image]

Comment: It shouldn't depend on project type. 
Is it reproducible in a just created HTML file that only contains a template?

What IDE version do you use?

Comment: do you have any custom plugins installed? please provide your idea.log (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files)

Comment: i am using webstorm IDE. 2018.2.3. I have many plugins installed how to identify which one is causing issue?